# Lua COM Programming

Tags: com, scripting, lua, photoshop, luacom

Anyone know of any examples that shows COM programming via Lua? Could require a library.

I need to write some external scripts for Photoshop, so wondering if it's possible with Lua.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Lua for Windows](http://luaforwindows.luaforge.net/).  It contains LuaCOM.  I haven't tried it myself, though.

Answer (score 3):

As gimpf said, take a look at LuaCOM. You can either get it from [its official site](http://luacom.luaforge.net/luacom-1.4.zip), which is the latest version (1.4). Unzip it somewhere and take a look at the folder "Demo", which includes examples for:

- ADO
- Powerpoint
- SAPI (Speech API)
- WMI

They are more like test cases than examples but you can get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can roll your own system using CInvoke and some custom C/C++ code combined with Lua meta-tables.

http://www.nongnu.org/cinvoke/

From experience though I can't recommend this, it is pretty complicated and requires a lot of effort to get it right and make it bulletproof.

Comment: Highly recommend C/Invoke.